# In ubuntu 18.04, how does apt-get showing 1 version in 2 different source as 2 versions?

Tags: 18.04, apt, aptitude

Recently ubuntu apt always try to upgrade libnvidia-common package with no effect, so I query this package and found 2 sources that are totally identical, one is from canonical & the other is from nvidia cuda ppa:

```
$ apt show libnvidia-common-450 -a
Package: libnvidia-common-450
Version: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: non-free/libs
Source: nvidia-graphics-drivers-450
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Installed-Size: 35.8 kB
Provides: libnvidia-common
Replaces: libnvidia-common, libnvidia-gl-450 (<< 390.25-0ubuntu2~)
Download-Size: 10.2 kB
APT-Sources: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  Packages
Description: Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
 This package provides a set of files that are required by the NVIDIA
 libraries.

Package: libnvidia-common-450
Version: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: non-free/libs
Source: nvidia-graphics-drivers-450
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Installed-Size: 35.8 kB
Provides: libnvidia-common
Breaks: libnvidia-gl-450 (<< 390.25-0ubuntu2~)
Replaces: libnvidia-common, libnvidia-gl-450 (<< 390.25-0ubuntu2~)
Homepage: http://www.nvidia.com
Download-Size: unknown
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
 This package provides a set of files that are required by the NVIDIA
 libraries.


$ aptitude show libnvidia-common-450
Package: libnvidia-common-450     
Version: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1
State: installed (450.36.06-0ubuntu1), upgrade available (450.36.06-0ubuntu1)
Automatically installed: yes
Priority: optional
Section: non-free/libs
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 35.8 k
Replaces: libnvidia-common, libnvidia-gl-450 (< 390.25-0ubuntu2~)
Provides: libnvidia-common
Description: Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
 This package provides a set of files that are required by the NVIDIA libraries.
```

So how do I avoid this situation?

Comment: Have you tried to remove sources that you don't want in your GUI package manager?  What about `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: I use cuda very often, why would I do that?

Comment: I know, and in this case both are not the latest, they are the same. My problem is that apt upgrade always leads to reinstalling the same package over and over